# Interrupt-based Equivalent of ctrl+alt+del on OS X

Tags: macos, interrupts

I'm looking for an equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> on Windows for OS X.

Note: I am *not* looking for <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> and this is *not* a duplicate of any questions asking for a "task manager".

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> on Windows uses an *interrupt* whereas <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> is just another keyboard shortcut. If the system is stuck (hung, etc.) <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> will not respond because it's just another user-mode program/dialog like any other.

I'm looking for an interrupt-based solution that will allow me to take control of an unresponsive system. OS X is (by and large) more stable than Windows, but when it gets stuck I have not found a solution as powerful as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> on Windows.

Comment: It won't work if the *kernel* is frozen (meaning driver error), but if Windows (userland) is frozen for some reason, ctrl+alt+del will work.

Comment: Windows isn't the kernel, it's the entire package. If userland is stuck because some random application is deadlocked and the scheduler farts and can't swap it out (which *does* happen), it's frozen. Let's not nitpick here, my question is obvious.

Comment: There might not be a difference, I've had `ctrl` + `alt` + `del` not work on Windows machines as well, in cases where I thought it should.

Comment: Holding ⌥⇧⌘⎋ for a few seconds force-quits the frontmost application. I doubt it works when ⌥⌘⎋ doesn't though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real equivalent. Either use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd>, or Force Quit the application.

Under the Apple menu, you will see force quit. You can either open this to choose an app, or hold shift while clicking force quit it will kill the frontmost app.

Comment: The reason I posted is because they're not working - the entire machine was locked up for a good 15 minutes. Hence my search for an interrupt-based option.

Comment: Well, that's probably as good as it gets.

Comment: I don't know if that Shift option still works with newer versions of Lion and Mountain Lion. Can someone else pls verify?

Answer (score -2):

This is likely not he answer you had in mind but if you have another computer, SSH into the problem MAC and kill -9 your stuck process.

This is what I do as a last resort.